# Logstash grok pattern to extract a part of String starts with and ends with

Tags: regex, logstash-grok

I am trying to extract the application Id.

As an example i need to extract

> application_1621858977521_0074

from the following log line

```
 /yarn/container-logs/application_1621858977521_0074/container_1621858977521_0074_01_000004 [2021-06-08 05:40:06,231] INFO Changing view acls groups to:  (org.apache.spark.SecurityManager)
```

I have tried the following custom grok pattern but doesn't work.

```
%{(^application_:/$):appID}%
```

I Appreciate your suggestions and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/(?<applicationId>application(?:_[0-9]+)+)/
```

Quick alternatives are:

```js
/(?<applicationId>application(?:_\w+)+)/
/(?<applicationId>application_[^/]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HvmvqY/2).

The pattern (with `/` added as path separators):

- `/` - a `/` char
- `(?<applicationId>application(?:_[0-9]+)+)` - Group "applicationId": `application` and then one or more repetitions of `_` and one or more digits
- `/` - a `/` char
- `[^/]*` - zero or more chars other than `/`.

The Grok debugger shows the following output with your given string:

```
{
  "applicationId": [
    [
      "application_1621858977521_0074"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you time. I applied this for the logstash grok it doesn't seem to work. You can try it here if you have time.  http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @Rashmikagamage That is where [I tested it, and it works](https://imgur.com/a/ZLb78Mt).

Comment: Oh Thank you!! But when I added the complete line                                                           /(?<applicationId>application(?:_[0-9]+)+)/ %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} %{LOGLEVEL:logLevel} %{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}  it doesn't work. Can you tell me why it is? Sorry I am a newbie

Comment: @Rashmikagamage Between this text and the timestamp, there is some more text, and you need to match this part, too. Try `(?<applicationId>application_[^/])[^ ]* \[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}\] %{LOGLEVEL:logLevel} %{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}`

Comment: @Rashmikagamage Sorry, left out a `*` quantifier, use `(?<applicationId>application_[^/]*)[^ ]* \[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}\] %{LOGLEVEL:logLevel} %{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}`

Comment: Hey it works with (?<applicationId>application_[^/]*)[^ ]* %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} %{LOGLEVEL:logLevel} %{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}

Comment: @Rashmikagamage [It is exactly where I test the expression](https://imgur.com/a/CNceuxv). If you need to double the ``\`` chars, do it.

Comment: it works with this (?<applicationId>application_[^/]*)[^ ]* %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} %{LOGLEVEL:logLevel} %{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}